# merge to objects array matching id

Tags: javascript

two arrays

```
arr1 = [
{id: 1, name: john doe},
{id: 2, name: uncle bob},
{id: 3, name: patrick star}
]

arr2 = [
{id: 1, gems: 500},
{id: 2, gems: 1000},
{id: 3, gems: 750},
{id: 2, gems: 8000},
{id: 3, gems: 7750},
{id: 1, gems: 1200},
{id: 3, gems: 950},
]
```

merge them together swapping id to their corresponding names and the sum of their gems?

expected output:

```
arr3 = [
{name: 'john doe', gems: 1700}
{name: 'uncle bob', gems: 9000}
{name: 'patrick star', gems: 9450}
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: @SethLutske i've tried reduce but only got the gems summed up and i cant seem a way to map it with the first array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
let arr1 = [
  {id: 1, name: 'john doe'},
  {id: 2, name: 'uncle bob'},
  {id: 3, name: 'patrick star'}
], arr2 = [
  {id: 1, gems: 500},
  {id: 2, gems: 1000},
  {id: 3, gems: 750},
  {id: 2, gems: 8000},
  {id: 3, gems: 7750},
  {id: 1, gems: 1200},
  {id: 3, gems: 950},
];
let arr3 = arr2.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
  let other = acc.find(({id})=>id===curr.id);
  other.gems = (other.gems || 0) + curr.gems;
  return acc;
}, arr1).map(({name,gems})=>({name,gems}));
console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: i got unexpected token at the ?? operator?

Comment: @Luispineda Looks like your browser doesn't support it then. I've updated my answer.